# how to run export bash command through C# process?

Tags: c#, bash

Trying to run export command through C# process :

**Current situation**

```
Process proc = Process.Start("export", "display=\":0.0\"");

proc.WaitForExit();

return proc.ExitCode;
```

**Part of the error**

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_shell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo                                                                                   startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:                                                                                  0
```

This is the way I did for all the commands and it always worked.

**Functional examples**

```
Process proc = Process.Start("kill", "810");
```

So why is it not working for export command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is a shell built-in *and* a binary on the system so it can be run without a shell.

```
$ type -a kill
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /bin/kill
kill is /usr/bin/kill
```

`export` is a shell-builtin only so you can't run `export` without a shell.

```
$ type -a export
export is a shell builtin
```

Additionally, even if you did get `export` to run like that it would only have an effect for the shell it ran in and not for your main process or any other processes run via `Process.Start`.

To set an environment variable that will be available to the current process and to other spawned processes later you need to modify the environment of the current process directly (via C#).

Comment: thanks a lot! However what do I do if I want this command to be run by a process and be set for all the following processes?

Comment: You set it in the environment of your current process in using C#.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I marked it as the answer. I feel like your latest comment could be really useful to the answer, if you don't mind I'll edit it to add it to the answer later?